# algebra. I dont understand

Tags: algebra-precalculus

write each ratio in lowest terms:  52 cards to 13 cards? 
I don't understand. That's all I have queston 1) is 52 cards to 13 cards and question 2) 7 days to 84 days.

Comment: You can write a ratio in lowest terms by dividing out the **greatest common factor** of each number.  For instance, with $52:13$ we see that the **gcf** of $52$ and $13$ is $13$.  Thus after dividing both numbers by $13$ we end up with $4:1$.  Now try $7:84$ on your own.

Comment: hint: there are 13 spades, 13 hearts, 13 diamonds, and 13 clubs in a standard deck. How many weeks are in 7 days? in 84 days? What do these two problems have in common?

Comment: As an amendment to my last comment, consider the recipe for a birthday cake http://allrecipes.com/recipe/7386/happy-birthday-cake/print/  Think about what you would have to do the ingredient (to simplify things just think about the ratio of sugar to flour [$2:3$]) if you wanted to make two cakes? what about $5$ cakes? how about $1/2$ a cake?

Answer (score 1):

Writing a ratio in lowest terms is just like [simplifying a fraction.](http://www.aaamath.com/fra66hx2.htm)

Here's my thought process when I solved this problem:

$52:13$

GCF of $52$ and $13$ is $13$

$52/13=13*4/13=4$

$13/13=13*1/13=1$

$4:1$

Now you should be able to find $7:84$ in lowest terms.